# bash trap with both optional and non-optional commands after error

Tags: bash, bash-trap

I'm struggling to understand how to use bash's `trap` command correctly.

I have a script where I want to

1. Do A
2. Do B, which might fail
3. Whether B succeeded or failed, do C
4. If B failed, also do D

I think I get how to do 1-3. That'd look something like;

```
echo "I am A"

function B {
   echo "I am C"
}
trap B EXIT

echo "I am B"
```

But where do I put D? If it goes inside function B, it executes whether or not B fails. If it's outside, it only happens on success. Am I using `trap` wrong?

Comment: `trap 'B || D' exit`?

Comment: Maybe [this discussion on SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67417/an-atexit-for-bash/208460#208460) will help?

Comment: your first comment is so simple but didn't even occur to me - if you can work that into a full answer I'd be happy to accept

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traps can use arbitrary code blocks instead of just function names.

You could make the call to the function *in the trap* evaluate success or failure and call the next function when required.

```
trap 'B || D' exit
```

You could allso make the whole `B || D` the body of an `E` and just call *that* on exit, if you prefer to stick to using function names. ;)